# Gradle/Java: generate resources with executable Java class

Tags: java, gradle

Situation is as follows:

- during the gradle build, I download and unzip resources from a dependency
- **one of the classes in the project** will process these resources, and **generate new resources to be included in the project** (as generated resources)

I managed to come up with a bit of a hacky solution, which runs the generator after the 'classes' task, and writes the resources to `$buildDir/resources/main/schema`:

```
ext {
    schemaGenerator = "org.something.JsonSchemaGenerator"
    serviceContractsDir = file("$buildDir/service-contracts")
    schemaOutputDir = file("$buildDir/resources/main/schema")
}

task jsonSchemas(type: Exec) {
    dependsOn classes
    dependsOn serviceContracts

    commandLine "java", "-classpath", sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath.getAsPath(), schemaGenerator, serviceContractsDir, schemaOutputDir
}

test.dependsOn jsonSchemas
assemble.dependsOn jsonSchemas
```

This works well, and the generated resources are then included in the JAR. 
But when uploading the artefacts, it will upload the JAR without the generated resources.

I made an attempt to do it the proper way:

```
ext {
    schemaOutputDir = file("$buildDir/generated-resources")
}

sourceSets.main.output.dir schemaOutputDir, builtBy: jsonSchemas
```

But then I end up with a **circular dependency**, as the resources are required by Gradle to build the classes, and the task to generate those resources also depends on the classes:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. 
> What went wrong: 
> Circular dependency between the following tasks: 
> :classes 
> --- :jsonSchemas 
>     --- :classes (*)

Is there a way to add them to the proper source sets (as `generated-resources`) so they are

- visible to tests
- included in the generated JAR?

Comment: You could add an additional sourceset and include this sourceset in the generated jar file.

Comment: instead of test/assemble - try jar.dependsOn - i.e. modify before jar is created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a new SourceSet that is independent of the main SourceSet should do the trick:

```
task jsonSchemas(type: Exec) {
  // same as above
}

sourceSets {
  schema {
    output.dir(schemaOutputDir, builtBy: 'jsonSchemas')
  }
  test {
    resources.srcDirs += [sourceSets.schema.output]
  }
}

jar {
  from sourceSets.schema.output
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm, and I even could get rid of the `dependsOn` declarations, thank you!